# Silverlight image flickering - how to avoid it

Tags: silverlight

I am writing a little game in SL, but have a big problem. There is an image called 'ship' I want to use as player. It moves with the "Canvas.SetLeft(ship,ship.X+ship.speed)" method, but it seens like flickering. I tried to set higher the gameloop timer interval, but it didnt help me out.
Around the internet i couldnt find anything about sl double buffer or something like that.

Hopefully You can help me: )

Hey

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to post a sample online somewhere that demonstrates this problem? Double buffering is not something that is necessary in Silverlight, and will not help in this situation.

One thing which you could try is to set enableGpuAcceleration="true" on the Silverlight plugin object and set CacheMode="BitmapCache" on the "ship" element. Without knowing what the problem you are running into is, I can't know if this will help or not, but it is worth trying.

Comment: This isn't an answer - it would be better as a comment.

Comment: Hi!
The problem is, that i move an image every 50ms if 'A' button is Down and its looks like flickering. I tried gpuacceleration before but it didnt help.: (

Comment: The flickering is not expected. Would you be able to share out a project that demonstrates this behavior?